Cmake build system for the GenericDictionary
The 3 cmake files presented here are the CMakeLists.txt files used to build the testing for the Generic Dictionary.
The builds and ctest work on Ubuntu 22.04. The builds previously worked on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2022, ctest has not been tested on Windows 10.
I'm looking for a general review on how I can improve the cmake files and the build.
Are the builds portable?
Are the builds and the tests maintainable?
The entire source code can be found on GitHub
It is taking about 4 seconds to build, but the CPU is 8 years old on the Ubuntu 22.04 system.
I am considering renaming testTest to GD_Test or GD_Unit_test.
Test coverage for the GenericDictionary.h file is currently 97.70% using gcov. While building the test binary does include the flags need to generate gcov on Ubuntu, the running of gcov has not been automated (yet). The test coverage for the entire test binary is 79%.
Top Level CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(TestDictionary LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)  

add_subdirectory(src/PerformanceTestGenerator)
add_subdirectory(src/tests)

PerformanceTestGenerator CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(createPerformanceTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(createPerformanceTest main.cpp PerformanceTestGenerator.cpp TestParameters.cpp)

target_compile_features(createPerformanceTest PUBLIC cxx_std_23)

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
    # warning level 4 and all warnings as errors
    target_compile_options(createPerformanceTest PRIVATE /W3 /WX -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
    if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
        # require at least gcc 12 to get full C++20 support
        if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 12)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "GCC version must be at least 12!")
        endif()
    endif()
    # lots of warnings and all warnings as errors
    target_compile_options(createPerformanceTest PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
endif()

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/performanceTest.h
  COMMAND createPerformanceTest --output-file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/performanceTest.h --test-count 3 --radix-16 --test-size 10 --test-size 20 --test-size ff --both-tests
  COMMENT "Generating performanceTest.h header file"
  VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(
  GeneratedHeader ALL
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/performanceTest.h
)

Tests Directory CMakeLists.txt
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(testTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(testTest testtest.cpp FunctionalityTests.cpp TestGenericDictionary.cpp)
add_dependencies(testTest GeneratedHeader)

target_include_directories(testTest
    PUBLIC ../..
    PRIVATE ./ ../PerformanceTestGenerator 
)

if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
        target_link_libraries(testTest gcov)
    endif()
endif()

target_compile_features(testTest PUBLIC cxx_std_23)

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
    # warning level 4 and all warnings as errors
    target_compile_options(testTest PRIVATE /W4 /WX -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
    if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
        # require at least gcc 12 to get full C++20 support
        if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 12)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "GCC version must be at least 12!")
        endif()
    endif()
    # lots of warnings and all warnings as errors
    target_compile_options(testTest PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
        target_compile_options(testTest PRIVATE -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage)
    endif()
endif()

if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    enable_testing()

    add_test(NAME testTest COMMAND testTest)

    set_property(TEST testTest PROPERTY PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "PASSED")
    set_property(TEST testTest PROPERTY FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "FAILED")
endif()



Avoid platform-specific code in your main CMake files
There is a lot of noise in your CMake files because of the platform-specific compile options.
First, try to find out if CMake doesn't already provide some function to do what you want in a platform-independent way. For example, to treat warnings as errors, you can set COMPILE_WARNINGS_AS_ERROR. I also am not sure why you are checking for "gcc 12 to get full C++20 support", when you already request C++23 support using set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23).
Why do you only enable testing if the compiler is GCC? Doesn't your test suite compile with any other compiler? That sounds like your code is buggy.
Finally, if there is still some platform-specific code left that you really cannot get rid of, move it out of your main CMake files, and put it in a separate file, inside a function, so it can be included by the main CMake files and called with a single line, so those main files stay small, clean and readable.
Avoid code duplication
You set CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD and CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED in all your CMakeLists.txt files, but if you put it in the topmost one, you don't have to repeat it in the files you include later. Code that enables treating warnings as errors, as well as anything else that is common for all subdirectories, could also be moved into the topmost file.
Naming things
testTest? Yo dawg! Is this testing a test? If so, it's a correct name, but you shouldn't be testing tests, otherwise you'd also have to write a test for the test testing the test, and so on, until it's tests all the way down. If it's running a test, it should just be named test without the echo.
Why is there both a FunctionalityTests.cpp and a TestGenericDictionary.cpp? Isn't the second one also just testing functionality? If so, it should just be merged into one file.
I strongly recommend you move and rename things so everything is clear, concise, consistent and without useless repetitions. I would move the test code into a directory named tests/ in the root of the source tree, so not inside src/, as that's usually where the implementation of the library and/or application lives. Also, it's then clear that everything inside tests/ is for tests, so there is no need to repeat the word test anymore. Then have files named:

/tests/performance.cpp
/tests/performance_generator.cpp
/tests/functionality.cpp

Don't create a /tests/test.cpp; you can have multiple add_test() statements, one for the performance test and one for the functionality test. Make sure the CMake target name matches the name of the main .cpp file for consistency.
You also don't need to put GD_ in the name if it's part of a repository named GenericyDictionaryCpp, it would just be redundant.
I'm not sure why some filenames have capitals and others don't. Be consistent. If you do have some rule to decide what to capitalize and what not, consider that I didn't see the logic, so it was of no use to me.
Treat CMake files like you would source code
As a general advise, treat non-source files the same way as you treat your actual source code. Also note that there are tools to automatically check and format CMake files, like cmakelang.

If I have multiple tests cases as multiple executables how do I build it, as far as I know cmake doesn't support building multiple executables in the same directory. Re: capitals in filenames, I thought in C++ class names should be capitalized and I name the file after the class. I also use camel case in file names, is this a bad practice?

If your answers are long you can use the GenericDictionary chatroom.

Only testing on Linux is clearly an error. I can only do test coverage on Linux since I don't have the tools to do test coverage on Windows, that lead to only testing on Linux.

“[...] as far as I know cmake doesn't support building multiple executables in the same directory.” I don't know why you think that, it's totally supported by CMake. “I thought in C++ class names should be capitalized and I name the file after the class.” There is no class FunctionalityTests though, so that is inconsistent. It's also not a hard requirement that type names are capitalized, it's just a common convention.

It took me a while, but I can see I got the testing all wrong because it was an after thought. I developed the tests as a stand alone program.
